How to apply data- attribute to rows from array of column headers
I have created a table in Angular using the column and row arrays at the bottom of this post. I have been trying to add a data-cell attribute to each row programmatically, which I have successfully done -- I just can't populate the attribute with data.
The desktop view is fine. On mobile devices, I am moving to a stacked version of the table (see image way at the bottom below the data) and I want to leverage the data-cell attribute to place the column headers above the appropriate cell data. If you look at the image, I want each column header to appear where the colons are currently appearing.
So far, I have the written this code. I just need a little help to get to the finish line, please and thank you.
    const tds = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('td'));

// Add data-cell attribute programatically
tds.forEach(td => {
  this.columns.forEach((col) => {
      td.setAttribute('data-cell', col.header)
  })      
})

  // I'm trying to end up with the following...
  // <td data-cell="Beverages"

})

=================================================================================
let columns: TableColumn[] = [
  {
    header: "Beverages",
    key: "name",
    sortable: true,
    cell: (item: any) => {
      return item.name;
    }
  },
  {
    header: "Cost",
    key: "cost",
    sortable: true,
    cell: (item: any) => {
      return item.cost;
    },
  },
  {
    header: "Text",
    key: "text",
    sortable: true,
    cell: (item: any) => {
      return item.text ? "Yes" : "No";
    },
  },
  {
    header: "Date",
    key: "date",
    sortable: true,
    cell: (item: any) => {
      return item.date;
    },
  },
  {
    header: "Unsortable",
    key: "unsortable",
    sortable: false,
    cell: (item: any) => {
      return item.unsortable;
    },
  }
]

let rows: any[] = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Water",
    cost: 100,
    text: true,
    date: "05021967",
    unsortable: "12 Fountain Street, Andover, MA"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Soda",
    cost: 250,
    text: false,
    date: "12121963",
    unsortable: "23 Oakland Avenue, Louisville, KY"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Coffee/Tea",
    cost: 50,
    text: true,
    date: "03111964",
    unsortable: "4 Maple Road, Stone Mountain, GA"
  }
]



What are this.columns and this.rows supposed to be? What is this in the context of your code?

this.rows and this.columns just refer to the data arrays -- It's an Angular project and the 'this' keyword is required in order to be able to access that data. It's a component I'm building, so I'm coding inside of the TableComponent class. Thanks.

Well, row.header can't be used outside the this.rows.forEach() loop.

But it's not clear what you're trying to do there. The td can only have one data-cell attribute, it doesn't make sense to do it repeatedly for each row.

It's not outside of it. It's inside.

It's inside tds.forEach but not inside this.rows.forEach.

I'm not sure why you're looping through all rows and columns for each td. It seems like you just need to get the row and column of that td. Or you should use nested loops for the rows and columns of the table.

@barmar I want a data-cell attribute for EACH td. Just one each, though. I'm able to add the SAME one to each td cell, but I need to loop through the headers and get a different one for each td. Thanks!

Maybe I don't know what I'm talking about because I don't know Angular. I've added the tag to the question.

Yeah, the nested loop is still a bit confusing to me. I have tried, but not succeeded. I do appreciate your thoughts.  I don't think Angular matters much. This is really a straight-up JavaScript knowledge gap for me. Thanks.

I have updated my code. It's starting to become more clear. Thanks for your help.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Use binding to "attr.data-cell"
<td [attr.data-cell]="col.header">

Yes, several atributes binding can not be directly by name also attr.+atribute_name
